# Act of the Prophet with Aisha

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah

I read on the Internet that Rasulullah (pbuh) used to, when entering the house, brush his teeth with miswak and then kiss 'Aisha with sucking her tongue.
My question is : Is it true or false ?

Answer (score 0):

The hadith you're referring to which is in Sunan Abu Dawud if I recall was graded daif by Al Albani.

Comment: And? Nevertheless there should be an explanation!